# Can't solve the Unhandled Runtime Error with NextJS and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm having a bug with NextJS and TypeScript. Does anyone know how to fix please help me solve this. I have searched and tried all the solutions but it still does not work. This is my bug:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined

Call Stack
attemptResolveElement
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1684:8)
attemptResolveElement
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1934:20)
resolveModelToJSON
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1399:13)
stringify
<anonymous>
stringify
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (2546:13)
processModelChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (2252:25)
retryTask
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (2299:6)
performWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1694:13)
listOnTimeout
node:internal/timers (569:17)
process.processTimers
node:internal/timers (512:7)
```

I tried to find a solution on Stack Overflow, google, facebook...
I expect to solve the bug and my app works properly.

Comment: Can you post your code?



 also please have a look at this article : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.